# Template repeat outside polymer element

Tags: polymer

Is something like this posible outside a Polymer element?

I want to be able to get data from a json and insert it as menu items, but what works fine inside a polymer element won't work here. Is there something I'm missing or this is impossible?

```
<html>
<head>
    [...]
</head>
<body>
<core-toolbar>
    <paper-menu-button id="dropDownMenu">
      <paper-icon-button id="iconomenuback" icon="menu" noink></paper-icon-button>
      <paper-dropdown class="dropdown colored" halign="left">
        <core-menu class="menu">
            <paper-item>Escritorio</paper-item>
            <template is="auto-binding">
            <custom-item-list id="list" items={{items}} jsonurl="postsESTADO CIVIL.json"></custom-item-list>
            <hr />
            <template is="auto-binding" repeat="{{item in items}}">
                <paper-item>
                    {{item.name}}
                </paper-item>
            </template>
           <%--<asp:Literal ID="MainMenuItems" runat="server"></asp:Literal>--%>
           <hr />
           </template>
           <paper-item>Panel de Control</paper-item>
        </core-menu>
      </paper-dropdown>
    </paper-menu-button>
</core-toolbar>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**
I'm trying a new approach, as seen in the [Polymer Single Page Application](https://www.polymer-project.org/articles/spa.html).

So far I'm still stuck. This is how my code looks right now:

```
  <paper-menu-button id="dropDownMenu" style="display:none;">
      <paper-icon-button id="iconomenuback" icon="menu" noink></paper-icon-button>
      <paper-dropdown class="dropdown colored" halign="left">
        <core-menu class="menu">
            <paper-item onclick="menuBackClick()">Escritorio</paper-item>                
            <hr />
            <template repeat="{{menuit, i in menuits}}">
                <paper-item>
                    {{menuit.Name}}
                </paper-item>                
            </template>
           <%--<asp:Literal ID="MainMenuItems" runat="server"></asp:Literal>--%>
           <hr />               
           <paper-item onclick="panercontrol()">Panel de Control</paper-item>
        </core-menu>
      </paper-dropdown>
    </paper-menu-button>
```

And this is the script I'm using, it gets the json from a file, extracts the data from it and then uses it.

```
<script>
    $.getJSON('api/mainmenu.json', function (data) {
        var template = document.querySelector('#fulltemplate');
        var itemsstring = JSON.stringify(data);
        template.menuits = itemsstring;
    });
</script>
```

At the moment it doesn't do anything, inspecting it returns plain `<template repeat="{{menuit, i in menuits}}"></template>` with nothing in it.

The #fulltemplate Template wraps all the content inside the body.

Comment: I would recommend you to use core-ajax and receive the data as JSON. [Here is a link to the tutorial](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/tutorial/step-3.html), try to follow their examples and you wont have to deal with things like this :)

Comment: I forgot to mention it, but my custom-item-list element works in the exact same way as post-service in the tutorial. I actually get a json from there, thats why I use it IN polymer elements and works, just doesn't outside polymer elements.

Comment: I am also new to Polymer, but maybe should look through the [Single Page Application](https://www.polymer-project.org/articles/spa.html) article. It might help you understand data-bindings :)

Comment: Well, I did exactly like in there, still not working. I'm updating my question with what I'm trying now

Comment: are you using a auto-binding template?

Comment: Yes, #fulltemplate Template (which wraps everything) is auto-binding